# How do I fetch the VLAN tags using libpcap and C?

Tags: c, libpcap, vlan

I am trying to parse a pcap file including different type of Network Packets (some are tagged as VLAN and some aren't) using #include .
here is my code so far:

```
pcap_t *pcap;
const unsigned char *packet;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
struct pcap_pkthdr header;
pcap = pcap_open_offline(argv[0], errbuf);
if (pcap == NULL)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "error reading pcap file: %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
}
while ((packet = pcap_next(pcap, &header)) != NULL)
{
    struct ip_header *ip;
    unsigned int IP_header_length;
    packet += sizeof(struct ether_header);
    capture_len -= sizeof(struct ether_header);
    ip = (struct ip_header*) packet;
    IP_header_length = ip->vhl * 4; /* ip_hl is in 4-byte words */
    char *sinfo = strdup(inet_ntoa(ip->src));
    char *dinfo = strdup(inet_ntoa(ip->dst));
    printf ("%s<-__->%s\n", sinfo ,dinfo);
    free (sinfo);
    free (dinfo);
}
```

There must be somewhere in the code to check the VLAN and jump over them correctly.How should I distinguish VLAN packets from non-VLANS?

Comment: Thank you for your well-formatted question, I am unsure however if you're asking 'how to best organize this code' or are you asking 'how do I fetch the VLAN tags using `libpcap`' and if so, are you targeting both 802.1q & ISL?

Comment: Thanks very much. I've change the Question. Yes, what I really want to see is just the IP header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If you are testing this on a 'live' environment, it's important to remember that routers can remove 802.1q tags before forwarding to a non-trunking line.)

If you have a particular platform & protocol in mind, the *fastest* way to do this will always be to 'manually' check a frame:

```
htonl( ((uint32_t)(ETH_P_8021Q) << 16U)
     | ((uint32_t)customer_tci & 0xFFFFU) ) T
```

However, `libpcap` provides for a portable & clean packet filters in the form of functions for [compiling a BPF filters](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_compile.3pcap.txt) and applying those to a stream of packets (although it is important to note that there are different sets of functions for on-the-wire vs. offline filtering)

In this fashion, We can use [`pcap_offline_filter`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_offline_filter.3pcap.txt) to apply the compiled BPF filter directive to a PCAP file. I've used the filter expression `vlan` here, you may want something else like `vlan or ip`. If you need something more complex, [you can consult the documentation](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html))

```c
...

pcap_t *pcap;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
const unsigned char *packet;
struct pcap_pkthdr header;
struct bpf_program fp; // Our filter expression
pcap = pcap_open_offline(argv[0], errbuf);
if (pcap == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error reading pcap file: %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
}

// Compile a basic filter expression, you can exam
if (pcap_compile(pcap, &fp, "vlan", 0, net) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't parse filter %s: %s\n", filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
    return 2;
}

while ((packet = pcap_next(pcap, &header) != NULL)
       && pcap_offline_filter(&fp, header, packet)) {
    struct ip_header *ip;
    unsigned int IP_header_length;
    packet += sizeof(struct ether_header);
    capture_len -= sizeof(struct ether_header);
    ip = (struct ip_header*) packet;
    IP_header_length = ip->vhl * 4; /* ip_hl is in 4-byte words */
    char *sinfo = strdup(inet_ntoa(ip->src));
    char *dinfo = strdup(inet_ntoa(ip->dst));
    printf ("%s<-__->%s\n", sinfo ,dinfo);
    free (sinfo);
    free (dinfo);
}

...
```